# What is wrong with my reasoning about this conditional probability problem?

Tags: probability

There is a box containing 6 red balls and 5 white balls. If the first drawn ball is red and not returned to the box, find the probability that a white ball is taken in the second drawn.

I have 3 solutions.The first two solutions produce the same but not for the last one. What is wrong with my reasoning?

### Solution 1 (simple logic)

After the first drawn there are 5 red balls and 5 white balls. The probability to take a white ball is $5/10 = 1/2$.

### Solution 2 (conditional probability)

Let 
\begin{align*}
A&=\{(x,y)\mid x \text{ is a red ball and } y \text{ is any ball} \}\\
A\cap B &=\{(x,y)\mid x \text{ is a red ball and } y \text{ is white ball} \}\\
S&=\{(x,y)\mid x \text{ is any ball and } y \text{ is any ball} \}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n(A)&=6\times 10\\
n(A\cap B)&=6\times 5\\
n(S)&=11\times 10
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P(A)&=\frac{6\times 10}{11\times 10}\\
P(A\cap B)&=\frac{6\times 5}{11\times 10}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
P(B\mid A)&=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}\\
 &= \frac{\frac{6\times 5}{11\times 10}}{\frac{6\times 10}{11\times 10}}\\
 &=\frac12
\end{align*}

### Solution 3 (permutation point of view)

All balls have numbers to uniquely identify each other.  The first and second drawn balls are placed separately in a different place each.

The number of elements in the sample space is $11\times 10$ (there are 11 ways to occupy the first place and 10 ways to occupy the second place). The number elements of the space of event in question is $6\times 5$ (there are 6 ways for red balls to occupy the first place and 5 ways for the  white balls to the second place).  The probability  is $\frac{6\times 5}{11\times 10} = \frac{3}{11}$.

Comment: I don't see why you have 11 choices for the first place; you know it is a red ball, so it can only be one of 6. You're not just choosing _any_ of 11 balls; you know it is red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your solution $3$ the sample space conists of only $6 \times 10$ possibilities, as the first ball must be red.

Comment: Ah... that is correct! Thank you!